# Angularjs firing request without request data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

First of all my apologies if the question is repeated.

I am making ajax requests using $q service.

```
        UtilityService.requestCall('/test/encrypt-data', {'json_string' : data_to_encrypt, 'encryption_key' : window.localStorage.getItem("Mi_Encryption_Key")})
        .then(function(encrypt_response) {
            var requestConoce = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("Mi_Cnonce")) + 1;
            window.localStorage.setItem("Mi_Cnonce", requestConoce);
            requestData['cnonce'] = requestConoce;

            requestData['encrypted_data'] = encrypt_response.data;
            return UtilityService.requestCall($scope.apiDetails.url, requestData, 'GET');
        })
        .then(function(api_response) {
            var requestConoce = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("Mi_Cnonce")) + 1;
            window.localStorage.setItem("Mi_Cnonce", requestConoce);

            return UtilityService.requestCall('/test/decrypt-data', {'encrypted_string' : api_response.encrypted_data, 'encryption_key' : window.localStorage.getItem('Mi_Encryption_Key') });
        })
        .then(function(decrypt_response) {
            $scope.serverResponse = JSON.stringify(decrypt_response);

            return;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert("Some Error");
        })





MyApp.factory('UtilityService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
return {
    requestCall: function(requestUrl, requestData, methodType) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var serverUrl = window.localStorage.getItem("Mi_Server_Url");
        $http({
            method: (methodType) ? methodType : "POST",
            url: serverUrl + requestUrl,
            data: requestData
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            deferred.resolve(result.data);
        },
        function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};}]);
```

I am making requests using the above code. It is working fine for the request "/test/encrypt-data"

But then request for `$scope.apiDetails.url` is not working. Request is made without any parameters But, I am sending all required parameters in `requestData`.

This code working for other (even I am sending the data) but not working for this request.

It seems angularjs requests two time for the same request once without data and other with data.

Please help for this strange issue. Please take a look on these images these are showing two different requests once with data and other without data.

[image: First Request]
[image]

Comment: What's in `$scope.apiDetails.url` and where exactly `requestData` is defined?

Comment: Yes, responseData is define and i am getting that in requestCall() and $scope.apiDetails.url is base url of my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are getting two requests because one of them is the OPTIONS call and one is the actual POST call. This is the normal behaviour and nothing to worry about.

The second request you are making is  a GET request which cannot contain any POST-Data. This is just not supported by HTTP.
So depending on what the backend is expecting you could either turn that request into a POST request or you could add the data as GET parameters which is described here: [in the Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

Comment: I have already tried with GET. But, there is no success. Server sending response for the OPTIONS method request with required fields errors. How to handle this situation

Comment: This has been resolved by query string for GET request instead on passing requestData in 'data'.